# Is it wrong to tag a user to ask their opinion?

Tags: support, tags, tagging

I was commenting with a fellow user on a question and after about five or so back and forth comments he never replied to my last comment. I left it six hours before making this comment

> @user Have you got any ideas?

He replied

> @Jordan please do not tag me to attract my attention I will reply in my own time

My question is, was it wrong of me to tag him in order to ask him of his opinion?

The reasoning behind tagging him was to ask of his opinion as he did not reply to my then previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't find it rude.  However, there are folks on here (this site especially), that work in the building trades.  Some of these folks might find it a bit annoying, to get notifications while they're sleeping or working.

I'd say it's a personal preference thing, and that it would depend on the situation.  However, for the most part, that's how tagging is supposed to work.  So I'd say you did nothing wrong. Just try to remember that this user doesn't like being pinged. When you interact with them in the future, don't ping them.